# Why character d & f ignored for oracle Number field in where condition?

Tags: database, oracle, conditional-statements

As I mentioned in question title,character `d` & `f` are ignored(?) in `Oracle where condition`

Below query runs without any error

```
select employee_id from employees where employee_id > 106f
```

But if I specify other than `d` or `f` after 106 `ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended` error will be thrown because `employee_id` is of datatype `Number`

**Why this Strange behaviour??** That to it happens for only single letter after number,if I specify `106df` it throws error(which is correct)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements003.htm), `d` and `f` are allowable suffixes for numeric literals, denoting 64-bit (**d**ouble) and 32-bit (**f**loat) binary floating-point types. In your case, the type doesn't make any difference (it probably just gets converted back to integer for the comparison, and with no loss of accuracy because 106 is small enough to be represented exactly as a float), so it looks like nothing is happening. Other letters, and `106df`, aren't allowed by the syntax. (`e` is allowed, but only if followed by a number.)

Comment: Thanks hobbs,great understanding!